# Comparing columns of current row and previous row in the same csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, indexing

So If someone has asked this question before, I am sorry ahead of time but I could not find an answer.

I have a data frame that looks like this, it is the output of a previous part of the code that writes to a file:
[image]

I have been trying to find a way to write a script to Check to see if a ResID goes from Bottom to Top (or the opposite) and if it does to create a dictionary counting how many times it switches from Bottom to Top. Its important to only check the iterations of that particular resID to see if it goes from bottom to top as that next Resid corresponds to a different ion which may not switch at all. Each Frame here corresponds to a different time frame of the same atom (ResID) and I am wanting to check if this atom goes from top to bottom over time.

I will eventually plot the dictionary values but am struggling to get the dictonary. I have tried just indexing off of the reader but that did not work
[image]

so then I tried to use iloc to index the file:
[image]

but this also did not work. How would I go about comparing the Location between a current row and a previous row if the ResId is the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to convert it to a list first and then iterate through the values.
[image]

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code, in your questions and answers. Pictures can't be searched, they can't be read with adaptive technology and anyone trying to recreate your problem or test your answer can't cut and paste your code.